# MAUT AppShell top blue bar

Tags: maui, app-shell, navigationbaritems

I’m trying to use a AppShell page to visualize 2 pages. I don’t want anything in the upper part of the page.. My code is the following

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MAUI_Diet_002.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAUI_Diet_002"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource DietMain}"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Names">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SearchByName}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Categories">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SearchByCategory}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
    
    
</Shell>
```

The first time I go on the Names page it looks like this.
[image]

But if I go to Categories page (that runs perfectly) and I come back to Names a top blue bar appears. And from that moment on it’s not possible to eliminate it.
[image]

I have  assigned `NavBarIsVisible=False`. I have also tryed to assign a color to the `NavigationBar` to see if it was really a `NavigationBar`, but the result was always the same

First question: what is the blue bar?  Not the Navigation, I suppose

Second: How can I remove it definitively?

Comment: That's still the (or *a*) navigation bar. What does the XAML (header) of your `SearchByName` and `SearchByCategory` pages look like? Have you tried setting `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` in each of those?

Comment: Yes I did. And I tryed also to change their color, but they remained the same. And they seam to be empty.

Comment: Based on your code, I created a demo, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I solved the problem. The first page of my app wasn't the AppShell, but a presentation page. I removed it.